# Finding shaded triangle areas in a parallelogram

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, quadrilateral

There is the following parallelogram involving two shaded triangles.

If I found rightly, angles of $AMD$, $BMN$ and $CDM$ are $45$. But I can’t go further.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

$\angle AMD$, $\angle BMN$ and $\angle CDM$ are not necessarily $45^\circ$.

---

$[\triangle AMD]=\dfrac12\times\dfrac23\times[ABCD]$

$[\triangle BMN]=\dfrac12\times\dfrac13\times\dfrac13\times[ABCD]$

$[\triangle CND]=\dfrac12\times\dfrac23\times[ABCD]$

$[\triangle DMN]=\left(1-\dfrac13-\dfrac1{18}-\dfrac13\right)\times[ABCD]=\dfrac5{18}[ABCD]$

So, $\dfrac5{18}[ABCD]=\dfrac12\times6\times10$

$[ABCD]=108$

$\textrm{shaded area}=\left(\dfrac13+\dfrac1{18}\right)\times 108 = 42$

Comment: how do you get the first three formulas $1/2 * 2/3 * [ABCD]$ and the rest?

Comment: $[\triangle ABD]=\frac12[ABCD]$. $[\triangle AMD=\frac23[\triangle ABD]$ as the two triangles have the same height and the ratio of the bases is $2:3$.

Comment: please if you don’t mind, would mind showing by drawing sir?

Comment: Let $h $ be the distance between $AB$ and $DC$. $[\triangle AMD]=\frac12\times AM\times h$. $AM=\frac23\times AB$. So, $[\triangle AMD]=\frac12\times\frac23\times AB\times h=\frac13\times[ABCD]$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $MN||AC$, we obtain:
$$S_{AMCD}=\frac{DM\cdot AC}{2}=\frac{10\cdot18}{2}=90.$$
Let $S_{\Delta BMC}=s$.

Thus, since $$\frac{S_{\Delta AMC}}{S_{\Delta BMC}}=\frac{AM}{MC}=2$$ and $$S_{\Delta ADC}=S_{\Delta ABC}=S_{\Delta AMC}+S_{\Delta BMC}=2s+s=3s,$$ we obtain: $$S_{AMCD}=S_{\Delta AMC}+S_{\Delta ADC}=2s+3s=5s,$$ which gives $$s=18.$$
Now, $$\frac{S_{\Delta BMN}}{S_{\Delta BMC}}=\frac{BM}{BC}=\frac{1}{3},$$ which says $$S_{\Delta BMN}=6.$$
Also, $$\frac{S_{\Delta DMA}}{S_{\Delta DBA}}=\frac{MA}{BA}=\frac{2}{3}.$$
Thus, $$S_{\Delta DMA}=\frac{2}{3}S_{\Delta DBA}=\frac{2}{3}S_{\Delta ABC}=\frac{2}{3}\cdot3s=\frac{2}{3}\cdot3\cdot18=36$$ and since $$36+6=42,$$ we are done!

Comment: sir, are you sure by saying area of $$?

Comment: Yes.  I used that $AC\perp MD.$

Comment: Humm, but I can’t infer the being perpendicular relationship. How did you get it?

Comment: @concurrencyboy Because $AC||MN$ and $MN\perp DM$.

Comment: But, the question doesn’t say anything about the being parallel relationship $||$ ?

Comment: @concurrencyboy It follows from $\frac{BM}{BA}=\frac{BN}{BC}.$ See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem

Comment: sir, don’t take me as geometry-disabled guy, but I can’t infer the relationship even from the given ratio. Would you mind more elucidating?

Comment: If  $\frac{BM}{BA}=\frac{BN}{BC}$ then $MN||AC$. It's the converse theorem to  the Thales' theorem. You can use also that $\Delta BMN\sim\Delta BAC.$

Comment: Humm, apparently I need to practice the theorem. Thank you. From your solution, can I reach the total shaded area?

Comment: Yes, of course. I can write a full solution.

Comment: I want to struggle with it. If I don’t get the result, I will apply your help. Thanks a lot sir.

Comment: You are welcome!